# Node.js control flow: callbacks or promises?

Tags: node.js, control-flow

I know there are many [control flow libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow) for node.js. Some of them let one chain async functions with callbacks (like async, asyncblock, etc), the others use [promise concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) (Q, deferred, futures, etc). Given a long running script making a series of actions one after another that may fail at any time, which control flow would you prefer and why? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 13):

Pros for callbacks:

- **Simple** to understand and create.
- Somewhat **more efficient**, because fewer objects are created and garbage collected.
- Node opted for `(error,result)` callbacks throughout.  I recommend following their argument order for consistency.  (As opposed to say `(result1, result2, result3, error)`.)

Pros for promises:

- Provides a **fluent interface**, which can sometimes help to mitigate nested callback hell, as [shown here](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/).  Code appears to flow linearly by chaining `.then(foo).then(bar)` calls.
- A good promises library will let you run many asynchronous operations in **parallel**, and continue only when they are all completed.  The [Deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred) library does this seamlessly through `map`, Q has `allResolved`, and ES6 Promises offer `Promise.all()`.  (This is also possible with callbacks, e.g. using [`async.parallel()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel), but not built in.)
- A good promises library will let you specify **one error handling function** which will be called if any of the queued functions fail.  To do this with callbacks requires a little boilerplate: `if (err) return callback(err);` at the start of every callback.

It would make sense to use **callbacks** near the **bottom of the stack**, for code which will be run many times per second.  Higher up the stack, promises may be preferable as they are easier to read and understand, and can handle errors more elegantly.

It is worth noting that **promises can be built from callbacks** at runtime.  So you can implement your core code in the minimalist callback form, and still expose a promises version of the library if you want to.  (As in `Q.nfbind()`.)

I would be interested to hear other pros/cons.

> Bonus tip: **Always handle errors!** With both methods, if you do not handle the error then it will simply disappear, leaving you in the dark about why your code did not work as expected.
>
> Callbacks should always handle `if (err) ...` and Promises should always have a `.catch()` if they do not return.
>
> Even if you expect errors sometimes, and don't need to handle those, not handling unexpected errors means you won't hear about errors from developer mistakes such as typos, if the code is changed in future.
>
> An alternative to `.catch()` for Promises is to listen for [unhandled rejections](https://gist.github.com/joepie91/06cca7058a34398f168b08223b642162).  Personally I use this to issue a warning that `.catch()` was missing!

Comment: More about perfs : http://thanpol.as/javascript/promises-a-performance-hits-you-should-be-aware-of/

Comment: link don't work anymore

Comment: Here is [an archived copy of Offirmo's perf link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160522044854/http://thanpol.as/javascript/promises-a-performance-hits-you-should-be-aware-of).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are many objective pros and cons.  Async is very popular (based on npm [packages that depend on it](http://search.npmjs.org/#/async)).

I like the control flow libraries (specifically async), because it is easier for me to understand.  Promises confuse me, while async is easily understandable.  I suspect its just a learning curve thing though, and promises would be more readable if I spent the effort in learning them.  But should I expect that of people trying to read my code too?

There is a 3rd type too - [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).  Fibers does not work on Windows yet, but (IMO) offers the clearest syntax for things that should execute in series.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with a declarative approach with this library: http://chainsjs.org still more work to do on it, but it gives you the ability to define an "execution map" where you can pretty much completely control the flow of execution from a simple mapping.

Comment: That site was down today but I found [a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20141217011058/http://chainsjs.org/) in the archive. There are a list of other control flow libraries [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#user-content-wiki-async-flow).

Comment: @joeytwiddle - thanks for the note, I never switched the IP when github pages changed IP. I just updated DNS, it should be back up soon.